# Recognise numbers from a Sudoku grid using pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, sudoku

I am making a sudoku solver and I want to be able to recognise numbers from a sudoku grid. I'm using pillow's cropping tool to cut out the squares and then see if they match a png of any of the numbers. But the function I made to crop out a square isn't consistent.

I've tried first resizing the image so that all the squares are going to be the same size, then cropping based on a row and column input, and then multiplying by a ninth of the image size. But that ended up including unnecessary lines that made the image different, so I shrunk the size of the crop. I tried many different offsets but none would work.

```
Sudoku = Image.open('image.png')
w,h = Sudoku.size
new_w = w//9*9
new_h = h//9*9
Sudoku = Sudoku.resize((new_w,new_h))

def get_square(r,c,cutoff):
  square_size = Sudoku.size[0]/9
  Top = r*square_size+cutoff
  Left = c*square_size+cutoff
  Bottom = (r+1)*square_size-cutoff
  Right = (c+1)*square_size-cutoff
  tup = (Left,Top,Right,Bottom)
  return Sudoku.crop(tup)
```

I expected the square to be shown normally and that numbers would always appear in the same place for each square. Instead when I save an image of a number in one square and then compare it with the same number from a different square, the numbers were shifted instead of lining up. 
Any ideas?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/fzy1995/SudokuImageSolver) git project

Comment: You may want to look at the MNIST problem for hand written digits: https://medium.com/@himanshubeniwal/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-machine-learning-ad30562a9b64

Comment: @mattsap If I can't think of how to fix it, or nobody else can help me, then that will be my decision. But since the digits aren't handwritten and are always the same, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Do you need to recognize the numbers or why not just store a variable in your grid cell object indicating the written number and the actual number?